# How to claim a controller in an adjacent room?

Tags: screeps

Having trouble claiming a  controller using a creep with one or more CLAIM body parts.

I am getting the nearest controller in the room using this function:

```
getNearestController: function(creep)
{
    return creep.room.find(FIND_STRUCTURES, {
    filter: function(structure) {
        return (structure.structureType == STRUCTURE_CONTROLLER);
    }
    });
}
```

Which works just fine, I can access the object and see it's coordinates are correct.

However, when I run this every tick (while the creep is directly next to it) the controller owner is still "None" and I see nothing happening, the creep takes no action.

```
if(creep.claimController(nearestController)<0)
{
    creep.moveTo(nearestController);            
}
```

Pretty sure the above call to claimController is incorrect, but not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: I think I know the answer - I do not have a spawner in the adjacent room. Heard from someone that you need to have one before claiming. Maybe I can still "reserve" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong here so I would think the problem is your Global Control Level.

In order to claim new rooms you need to have a GCL at least 1 higher than the number of rooms you already own. If you're a new player your GCL is probably still at level 1. This would mean you can own just one room. You can look at your game profile to see your progress towards the next level.

http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203086021-Global-control

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing. The problem seems to be that you **claimController** returns some kind of error (most probably the ERR_GCL_NOT_ENOUGH). Make sure you check the return codes of your creeps' actions. Here is my example, where I move to controller if it is not in range. If the creep is in range, it tries to claim it. If it fails on ERR_GCL_NOT_ENOUGH, it tries to reserve it. Otherwise it logs the problem.

```
  // try to claim controller
  let r = creep.claimController(creep.room.controller);
  if (r === ERR_NOT_IN_RANGE) {
    // move towards the controller
    creep.moveTo(creep.room.controller);
  } else if (r === ERR_GCL_NOT_ENOUGH){
    creep.say('NO GCL->reserving');
    let re = creep.reserveController(creep.room.controller);
    if (re !== 0) {
      console.log('Claimer reserving error: ' + re);
      creep.moveTo(creep.room.controller);
    }
  } else if (r !== 0) {
    console.log('Claimer error: ' + r);
  }
```